# Why can't sectsty change the chapter font when it's used with babel package?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, babel, sectsty, hungarian

I'm using Latex to write my thesis in Hungarian, so I include in the preamble the following:

```
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
```

Once this is loaded, I get "Chapter", "Figure", etc. in Hungarian and with matching typography.

I would like to use a sans-serif font in chapter, section and subsection headings. To achieve this, I use the `sectsty` package, set up like this:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} 
\sectionfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\Large}
```

LaTeX correctly sets sections and subsections in `TeX Gyre`, but chapter headings stay unchanged, while unnumbered chapters (`\chapter*{...}`)
get changed like they are supposed to.

Example:

[image: Chapter font remain unchanged]

while

[image: See image.]

I suspect the conflict is caused by `babel`, which redefines the chapter heading in some way `sectsty` won't be able to handle.

Does anyone have any idea how to manage this? I have tried titlesec, but it behaves in the same way.

Thank you!

Edit:

I created a short document with every relevant package to recreate the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} 
\sectionfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\Large}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Example chapter} %% this one is not working correctly

    \blindtext

    \section{Example section}

    \blindtext

    \subsection{Example subsection}

    \blindtext

    \chapter*{Example unnumbered chapter}

    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

If I comment out `babel`, `sectsty` works as expected but I lose the localization obviously.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a compilable document, not just fragments only

Comment: Please also tell us which document class you use.

Comment: I use report, since I need chapters and article doesn't have those. I can post a compilable document, but where can I submit it? As an answer?

Comment: You can edit your own question to post code.

Comment: @1amarr: The problem seems to be `magyar`, it works with `english`, but this does not really help you

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: thought so... I have looked into the .ldf file `babel` is using with `magyar`, but it's way too complicated for me to notice any obvious changes which prevent `sectsty` functioning like it's expected.

Comment: @1amarr: I experimented with basically any European language setting for `babel` and `magyar` is the only one that fails here. I assume, it's `magyar.ldf`, but I am not sure

Comment: Thank you.  Since I absolutely need `babel`, I think the only possible solution is to experiment with `magyar.ldf` so that it leaves `\chapter` unchanged and  manually redefine `\chapter` so that it matches the localisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `magyar` option seizes the initiative and changes the code for `\@chapter` to reflect the original code in the class and ignores the settings by `sectsty`. It does nothing to `\@schapter`, which is the reason you see sans serif in unnumbered chapters.

Use `titlesec`, instead:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 

\usepackage[sf,bf]{titlesec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand\magyarOptions{chapterhead=unchanged}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qhv}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\sffamily\bfseries\huge}
  {\thechapter. \chaptername}
  {20pt}
  {}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Example chapter} %% this one is not working correctly

\blindtext

\section{Example section}

\blindtext

\subsection{Example subsection}

\blindtext

\chapter*{Example unnumbered chapter}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\def\magyarOptions{chapterhead=unchanged}` before `\usepackage[magyar]{babel}`

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\def\magyarOptions{chapterhead=unchanged}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} 
\sectionfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\Large}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Example chapter} %% this one is not working correctly
    \blindtext
    \section{Example section}
    \blindtext
    \subsection{Example subsection}
    \blindtext
    \chapter*{Example unnumbered chapter}
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's close, but I need the heading displayed as "n. fejezet" where "n" is the number of the chapter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\chapterfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\huge} 
\sectionfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\usefont{T1}{qhv}{b}{n}\selectfont\Large}
\makeatletter
\let\mt@makechapterhead\@makechapterhead
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\let\@makechapterhead\mt@makechapterhead
\makeatother
    \chapter{Example chapter} %% this one is not working correctly

    \blindtext

    \section{Example section}

    \blindtext

    \subsection{Example subsection}

    \blindtext

    \chapter*{Example unnumbered chapter}

    \blindtext

\end{document}
```